# Multiple Prompt Response Card in Slack

Tags: python, aws-lambda, slack-api, amazon-lex

I am currently doing a chatbot on amazon lex and deployed it on slack. But somehow whenever try it out and it reaches the response card question, it posts the prompt question duplicate times. How do I make it prompt only once or is it just a problem from Slack?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code in used in aws lambda, however, I did the settings for response card on lex and nothing on aws lambda:

```
import json
import datetime
import time
import os
import dateutil.parser
import logging
import urllib.request

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# --- Helpers that build all of the responses ---


def elicit_slot(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, slot_to_elicit, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ElicitSlot',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'slotToElicit': slot_to_elicit,
            'message': message
        }
    }


def confirm_intent(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ConfirmIntent',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'message': message
        }
    }


def close(session_attributes, fulfillment_state, message):
    response = {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': fulfillment_state,
            'message': message
        }
    }

    return response

def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }

# --- Helper Functions ---

def safe_int(n):
    """
    Safely convert n value to int.
    """
    if n is not None:
        return int(n)
    return n


def try_ex(func):
    """
    Call passed in function in try block. If KeyError is encountered return None.
    This function is intended to be used to safely access dictionary.

    Note that this function would have negative impact on performance.
    """

    try:
        return func()
    except KeyError:
        return None

def calculate_age(birthday, combine):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    birthdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d')
    age = today.year - birthdate.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthdate.month, birthdate.day))
    age = age + 1

    age2 = age + 10

    request = urllib.request.Request('https://insuranceproject-ae18a.firebaseio.com/%d/%s.json' % (age, combine[0].replace(' ', '')))
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    str_response = response.read()
    info = json.loads(str_response.decode("utf-8"))

    request = urllib.request.Request('https://insuranceproject-ae18a.firebaseio.com/%d/%s.json' % (age2, combine[0].replace(' ', '')))
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    str_response = response.read()
    info2 = json.loads(str_response.decode("utf-8"))    

    abc = [info, str(age), info2]

    return abc

def cash_outlay(abc):
    age = int(abc[1])
    if (age <= 40):
        awl = 300
    elif(age <= 70):
        awl = 600
    else:
        awl = 900

    premium = int(abc[0])
    if (premium > awl):
        cash_outlay = premium - awl
        say = " Since your premium is more than your AWL (Additional Withdrawal Limit), u only need to pay the remaining which is $" + str(cash_outlay)
    else:
        cash_outlay = 0
        say = " Since your premium is less than AWL (Additional Withdrawal Limit), everything is settled by Medisave"

    return say

def generate_rec_plan(ward_type, compensation, period, limit):
    if(ward_type == 'Private' and period == '4' and limit == 'Yes'):
        plan_type = 'AXA Shield Plan A'
        link = 'https://www.axa.com.sg/our-solutions/personal/health/axa-shield'
    elif(ward_type == 'Private' and period == '4' and limit == 'No'):
        plan_type = 'PRUshield A Premier'
        link = 'https://www.prudential.com.sg/en/our-solutions/products/prushield/'
    elif(ward_type == 'Private' and period == '3' and limit == 'Yes'):
        plan_type = 'Supreme Health P Plus'
        link = 'https://www.greateasternlife.com/sg/en/personal-insurance/find-the-right-plan/protect-myself-and-my-family/health-protection/supremehealth.html'
    elif(ward_type == 'Private' and period == '3' and limit == 'No'):
        plan_type = 'My Shield Plan 1'
        link = 'https://www.aviva.com.sg/en/insurance/life-and-health/my-shield/'
    elif(ward_type == 'Private' and period == '2'):
        plan_type = 'Preferred'
        link = 'https://www.income.com.sg/insurance/health-insurance/enhanced-incomeshield'
    elif(ward_type == 'Private' and period == '1'):
        plan_type = 'AIA Health Shield Gold Max A'
        link = 'https://www.aia.com.sg/en/our-products/medical-protection/aia-healthshield-gold-max.html'
    elif(ward_type == 'A ward' and period == '4' and limit == 'Yes'):
        plan_type = 'PRUshield A Plus'
        link = 'https://www.prudential.com.sg/en/our-solutions/products/prushield/'
    elif(ward_type == 'A ward' and period == '4' and limit == 'No'):
        plan_type = 'AXA Shield Plan B'
        link = 'https://www.axa.com.sg/our-solutions/personal/health/axa-shield'
    elif(ward_type == 'A ward' and period == '3'):
        plan_type = 'Supreme Health A Plus'
        link = 'https://www.greateasternlife.com/sg/en/personal-insurance/find-the-right-plan/protect-myself-and-my-family/health-protection/supremehealth.html'
    elif(ward_type == 'A ward' and period == '2'):
        plan_type = 'AIA Health Shield Gold Max B'
        link = 'https://www.aia.com.sg/en/our-products/medical-protection/aia-healthshield-gold-max.html'
    elif(ward_type == 'A ward' and period == '1' and limit == 'Yes'):
        plan_type = 'MyShield Plan 2'
        link = 'https://www.aviva.com.sg/en/insurance/life-and-health/my-shield/'
    elif(ward_type == 'A ward' and period == '1' and limit == 'No'):
        plan_type = 'Advantage'
        link = 'https://www.income.com.sg/insurance/health-insurance/enhanced-incomeshield'
    elif(ward_type == 'B1 ward' and compensation == 'As Charged' and (period == '4' or period == '3')):
        plan_type = 'Supreme Health B Plus'
        link = 'https://www.greateasternlife.com/sg/en/personal-insurance/find-the-right-plan/protect-myself-and-my-family/health-protection/supremehealth.html'
    elif(ward_type == 'B1 ward' and compensation == 'As Charged' and period == '2'):
        plan_type = 'AIA Health Shield Gold Max B Lite'
        link = 'https://www.aia.com.sg/en/our-products/medical-protection/aia-healthshield-gold-max.html'
    elif(ward_type == 'B1 ward' and compensation == 'As Charged' and period == '1' and limit == 'Yes'):
        plan_type = 'My Shield Plan 3'
        link = 'https://www.aviva.com.sg/en/insurance/life-and-health/my-shield/'
    elif(ward_type == 'B1 ward' and compensation == 'As Charged' and period == '1' and limit == 'No'):
        plan_type = 'Basic - SG'
        link = 'https://www.income.com.sg/insurance/health-insurance/enhanced-incomeshield'
    elif(ward_type == 'B1 ward' and compensation == 'Limits'):
        plan_type = 'AXA Standard Plan'
        link = 'https://www.axa.com.sg/our-solutions/personal/health/axa-shield'
    elif(ward_type == 'B2 or C ward' and compensation == 'As Charged'):
        plan_type = 'Enhanced C - SG'
        link = 'https://www.income.com.sg/insurance/health-insurance/enhanced-incomeshield'
    elif(ward_type == 'B2 or C ward' and compensation == 'Limits'):
        plan_type = 'Medishield Life'
        link = 'https://www.moh.gov.sg/content/moh_web/medishield-life/about-medishield-life/medishield-life-benefits.html'
    combine = [plan_type, link]

    return combine

def isvalid_date(date):
    try:
        dateutil.parser.parse(date)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def isvalid_nationality(nationality):
    nationality_types = ['Singapore Citizen', 'Permanent Resident', 'Foreigner']
    return nationality in nationality_types

def isvalid_compensation(compensation):
    compensations = ['Limits', 'As Charged']
    return compensation in compensations

def isvalid_period(period):
    periods = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    return int(period) in periods

def isvalid_limit(limit):
    limits = ['Yes', 'No']
    return limit in limits

def build_validation_result(isvalid, violated_slot, message_content):
    return {
        'isValid': isvalid,
        'violatedSlot': violated_slot,
        'message': {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': message_content}
    }    

def validate_insurance_plan(slots):
    birthday = try_ex(lambda: slots['birth'])
    nationality = try_ex(lambda: slots['nation'])
    isp = try_ex(lambda: slots['isp'])
    ward_type = try_ex(lambda: slots['ward'])
    compensation = try_ex(lambda: slots['compensation'])
    period = try_ex(lambda: slots['period'])
    limit = try_ex(lambda: slots['limits'])    

    if birthday:
        if not isvalid_date(birthday):
            return build_validation_result(
                False, 
                'birth', 
                'I did not understand your birthdate. When were you born?'
                )
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d').date() > datetime.date.today():
            return build_validation_result(
                False, 
                'birth', 
                'You are not even born yet, how is this possible. Please tell me your correct birthdate.'
                )

    if nationality and not isvalid_nationality(nationality):
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'nation',
            'Sorry but the stated nationality does not exist, please choose from ones stated [Singapore Citizen, Permanent Resident, Foreigner]'
        )

    if compensation and not isvalid_compensation(compensation):
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'compensation',
            'Sorry but that plan does not exist, please choose either a plan with "As Charged" coverage or a plan with "Limits".'
            )

    if period and not isvalid_period(period):
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'period',
            'Please choose a number between 1-4'
        )

    if limit and not isvalid_limit(limit):
        return build_validation_result(
            False,
            'limits',
            'Please answer Yes/No, it"s that simple.'
        )

    return {'isValid': True}


""" --- Functions that control the bot's behavior --- """
def introduction(intent_request):

    session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}

    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Hey there! Try asking me "Which integrated Shield Plan is right for me?" to find out your recommended Insurance Plan!'
        }
    )


def insurance_bot(intent_request):

    birthday = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['birth'])
    nationality = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['nation'])
    isp = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['isp'])
    ward_type = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['ward'])
    compensation = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['compensation'])
    period = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['period'])
    limit = try_ex(lambda: intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']['limits']) 

    session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}

    last_confirmed_insurance = try_ex(lambda: session_attributes['lastConfirmedInsurance'])
    if last_confirmed_insurance:
        last_confirmed_insurance = json.loads(last_confirmed_insurance)
    confirmation_context = try_ex(lambda: session_attributes['confirmationContext'])

    # Load confirmation history and track the current reservation.
    insurance = json.dumps({
        'birth': birthday,
        'nation': nationality,
        'isp': isp,
        'ward': ward_type,
        'compensation': compensation,
        'period': period,
        'limits': limit
    })

    session_attributes['currentInsurance'] = insurance

    if intent_request['invocationSource'] == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # Validate any slots which have been specified.  If any are invalid, re-elicit for their value
        validation_result = validate_insurance_plan(intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])
        if not validation_result['isValid']:
            slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
            slots[validation_result['violatedSlot']] = None

            return elicit_slot(
                session_attributes,
                intent_request['currentIntent']['name'],
                slots,
                validation_result['violatedSlot'],
                validation_result['message']
            )

        #If user is foreigner, straight away end chat
        if nationality == 'Foreigner':

            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('currentInsurance'))
            session_attributes['lastConfirmedInsurance'] = insurance            

            return close(
                session_attributes,
                'Fulfilled',
                {
                    'contentType': 'PlainText',
                    'content': 'I am sorry but foreigners currently cannot apply for an insurance plan in Sg.'
                    + ' It it still under development '
                    + 'so look out for it in the future! Thank you and have a nice day!'
                }
            )

        #Getting recommended plan, age and premium info
        if birthday and ward_type and compensation and period and limit:
           plan = generate_rec_plan(ward_type, compensation, period, limit)
           session_attributes['recPlan'] = plan[0]
           session_attributes['planLink'] = plan[1]

           info = calculate_age(birthday, plan)
           session_attributes['premium'] = info[0]
           session_attributes['age'] = info[1] 
           session_attributes['age2'] = info[2]

           outlay = cash_outlay(info)
           session_attributes['cashOutlay'] = outlay 
        else:
            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('recPlan'))
            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('planLink'))
            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('premium'))
            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('age'))
            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('age2'))
            try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('cashOutlay'))

        session_attributes['currentInsurance'] = insurance
        return delegate(session_attributes, intent_request['currentIntent']['slots'])

    # Booking the hotel.  In a real application, this would likely involve a call to a backend service.
    logger.debug('InsurPlan under={}'.format(insurance))

    try_ex(lambda: session_attributes.pop('currentInsurance'))
    session_attributes['lastConfirmedInsurance'] = insurance

    return close(
        session_attributes,
        'Fulfilled',
        {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': 'Your recommended plan would be ' + session_attributes['recPlan'] 
            + '! And since you are ' + session_attributes['age'] 
            + ' next year, you will be given a premium of about $'  + session_attributes['premium']
            + '. '
            + session_attributes['cashOutlay']
            + '. But in 10 years, your premium will be $' + session_attributes['age2'] 
            + '. If you want to know more about this insurance plan, you can go to ' 
            + session_attributes['planLink'] + ' for more details!'
        }
    )


# --- Intents ---


def dispatch(intent_request):
    """
    Called when the user specifies an intent for this bot.
    """

    logger.debug('dispatch userId={}, intentName={}'.format(intent_request['userId'], intent_request['currentIntent']['name']))
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']

    # Dispatch to your bot's intent handlers
    if intent_name == 'InsurePlan':
        return insurance_bot(intent_request)
    elif intent_name == 'Intro':
        return introduction(intent_request)

    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')


# --- Main handler ---

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return dispatch(event)
```

[image]

Comment: it all depends what intent is being revoked by the input. check your logs for details, that might help.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say here, so the reason why it prompts duplicate times is because there is more than 1 intent?

Comment: no, i am saying maybe for these inputs same intent is being called resulting in this response card. you should check your CloudWatch logs for different inputs to see how the process is happening.

Comment: post your code and logs so that people can help you better, otherwise we all will keep guessing the things.

Comment: Added my codes already, but for response card, I only edited it on amazon lex and not in aws lambda

Comment: is the slot **isp** for intent **InsurePlan** is checked as **required**? that might be invoking this.

Comment: Yep, it's checked. So I should unchecking it then?

Comment: yes, ading details in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It seem like your slot `isp` for intent `InsurePlan` is **checked as required**, that's why when the intent is being invoked it is checking that slot value for `isp` is not fulfilled and it is showing prompt message (response card) in your case.

You should uncheck the slot `isp` and check it's value in `DialogCodeHook` and provide `ElicitSlot` when required. And try to provide response card from code instead of console, that is more customizable.

Hope it helps.